# Show that the integral of $U^2$ of the Korteweg De Vries equation is invariant

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the integral of $U^2$ of the Korteweg De Vries equation is invariant.

$$U_t+UU_x = DU_{xxx}$$

where $D$ is a constant.

I have tried differentiating $U^2$ w.r.t time and using integration by parts but no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the integral of $U$ over $x$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
E(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty U(x,t)^2\,\text{d} x.
\end{equation}
To prove that $E(t)$ is invariant, i.e. that $\frac{\text{d} E}{\text{d} t} = 0$, you'll only need to integrate the $U_{xxx}$ term by parts. As an additional hint, try to use the following derivatives to $x$:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} U^3\quad\text{and}\quad  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} U_x^2.
\end{equation}

Comment: Why do I only need to integrate $U_{xxx}$ ?

Comment: You'll find out when you substitute the Korteweg-de Vries equation in the expression for $\frac{\text{d} E}{\text{d} t}$. If you're stuck at some point, I suggest you post your attempts at an answer.